# Recovering a function from its partial differential

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, differential

If I have a function of two variables, say $f=f(x,y)$, I know that its differential is computed as $$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dx$$
But is it possible to recover the original function from the differential? For instance if I have:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-\frac{A}{2y}; \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{Ax}{2y^2}$$
How may i proceed to compute the original function $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Suppose that you have a 1-form $\omega = g(x,y)dx + h(x,y)dy$ on an open disk. Then $\omega = df$ for some function $f$ if and only if the form $\omega$ is exact, i.e., the cross-partial condition is satisfied: $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}. $$ This is a special case of the Poincaré lemma.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized an error in the example above and now I can see that the cross-partial condition is satisfied.